# Auto translate content of nodes

Tags: 7, nodes, i18n-l10n

I am developing a Drupal 7 site, where i store the content of a cotent type(with several fields).
So by default, i enter the English text for the content and save it.

Is it possible in Drupal to automatically translate the content in English to other languages like French, Spanish, German, etc? I have been experimenting with several modules like Content Translation, which provide the option to enter content manually in other languages. But i don't like to enter the content separately for each language, rather i like to automatically translate it with the click of a button. Is there such a module or feature in Drupal 7 ?

As a final alternative, i thought to use an API like Google Translator in the background, when saving my node content, but i hope there is a module available for automatic content translation.

Note: I am not interested in using any widget on the front end, for content translation. Instead, i prefer admin to translate content with one click in the backend.

Answer (score 3):

**It will never be good.** Human languages are not something perfectly unambiguous and logical*, so no computer software will ever be able to translate them perfectly. **You need a human to properly translate human languages**.

Google Translate is bad, but I haven't seen anything better. Sadly, [Translate API got deprecated](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2011/05/spring-cleaning-for-some-of-our-apis.html) in 2011. This means that modules using it may work for now, but may stop working without notice. See [GTranslate](https://www.drupal.org/project/gtranslate) and [i18n auto translate](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n_auto).

You can always use some code from above modules, and try another machine translator. See [Comparison of machine translation applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_machine_translation_applications) article - deciding which one to implement is outside the scope of Drupal Answers, just remember that you want GPL software if you want to mix it with contrib modules' code without fees or legal risk.

---

* OK, there is Lojban, but that's an exception.

[image: zo'o ta jitfa .i .e'o xu do pendo mi]

Comment: I think Gtranslate is [no longer free](http://gtranslate.net/?xyz=1002) and coming to i18 auto translate, This module has been deprecated by the new [Translation Management Tool](https://www.drupal.org/project/tmgmt) for Drupal 7

Comment: @KrishnaMohan Well, good points, but [shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) was not meant to be important part of my answer anyway.

Comment: So is the Translation Management tool for Drupal 7 capable of converting the node content automatically into other languages, or even that needs a person to manually feed content in a language?

Comment: @shasi Please read module's page before asking, OK? Second sentence answers your comment above!

Answer (score 2):

It's 2018 and a lot has changed in machine translation since this question was asked. My testing shows, that for example Google Translate is surprisingly usable also for such translation pairs as Slovak <-> English, which just couple of years ago was terrible. Additionally, there is the [Translation Management Tool](https://www.drupal.org/project/tmgmt) module for Drupal 7 and 8 that supports both - manual as well as machine translations for entities or even strings. A number of "human" and a couple of machine translation service providers can be utilized for the actual text translation in that module.